# Do towers and/or minions regenerate health?

Tags: league-of-legends

Do **towers** get ***health*** back if left alone long enough and same for **minions** down lanes?

Answer (score 5):

Only the Nexus and the two towers around it.

The small exception is if you have a Heimerdinger on your team.

As long as he stands by any structure, it will slowly regenerate health.

Comment: Would minions heal over time like champs?

Comment: Heimerdinger's passive applies to all allied units and structures, so yes.

Comment: As of Patch 3.13, Heimerdinger no longer regenerates structures, and inhibitor turrets have been given health regeneration with Season 4 and so this information is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

No, they do not regenerate health.